# value if $a$ for which biquadratic equation has $2$ distinct negative roots.

Tags: calculus

> If the equation $x^4+2ax^3+x^2+2ax+1=0$ has at least $2$ Distinct negative roots. Then values of $a$ is

Try: If $x\neq 0$, Then we can write equation as $$x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+2a\bigg(x+\frac{1}{x}\bigg)+1=0$$

put $\displaystyle x+\frac{1}{x}=t$. Then equation is $t^2+2at-1=0$

For real roots, Then discriminant $\geq 0$ So $4a^2+4\geq 0$

which is true for all real $a$

But answer is different. Could some help me to solve it , thanks

Comment: As you assume $x$ to be real, $|t|\ge2$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for each $a\in\mathbb R$ the equation $t^2+2at-1=0$ has two real roots. Problem: the equation $x+\frac1x=t$ has a solution (in $\mathbb R$) when and only when $t\geqslant2$ or $t\leqslant-2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$t=x+\frac{1}{x}\tag{1}.$$

From the assumption $x\in\mathbb{R},x<0$ follows $t\in\mathbb{R},t\le-2$.

Observe that for $t<-2$ there are exactly two distinct negative values of $x$ $(x_1x_2=1)$ satisfying (1).

Further the equation
$$
t^2+2at-1=0\tag {2}
$$
together with $t\in\mathbb{R}$ implies $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

For the negative root  of (2) we should require: 
$$-a-\sqrt{a^2+1}<-2 \Rightarrow (2-a)<\sqrt{a^2+1} \Rightarrow (2-a)^2<a^2+1\Rightarrow \frac{3}{4}<a.
$$

It can be shown that with this choice of $a $ *exactly* too roots of original equation are negative reals as the other two roots are a pair of complex conjugated numbers.